# Practically, what is the difference between docker run -dit(-itd) vs docker run -d?

Tags: docker

I've used `docker run -it` to launch containers interactively and `docker run -d` to start them in background. These two options seemed exclusive. However, now I've noticed that `docker run -dit` (or `docker run -itd`) is quite common. So what is the difference? When `-it` is really needed together with `-d`?

Comment: `-i` starts an interactive session and `-t` emulates a tty. But `-d` tells Docker to detach and run in the background. They don't really make sense together...

Comment: @DanLowe That's why I asked. It is used on [docker site](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/container_update/) and elsewhere.

Comment: Yeah you do have a point. I thought maybe it would change behavior of `docker attach` ... but I don't see any difference. Good question.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Yes, sometimes, it's necessary to include `-it` even you `-d`

1. When the `ENTRYPOINT` is `bash` or `sh`

   `docker run -d ubuntu:14.04` will immediately stop, cause `bash` can't find any pseudo terminal to be allocated. You have to specify `-it` so that `bash` or `sh` can be allocated to a pseudo terminal.

   ```
    docker run -dit ubuntu:14.04
   ```
2. If you want to use `nano` or `vim` with any container in the future, you have to specify `-it` when the image starts. Otherwise you'll get error. For example,

   ```
    docker run --name mongodb -d mongo
    docker exec -it mongodb bash
    apt-get update
    apt-get install nano
    nano somefile
   ```

   It will throw an error

   `Error opening terminal: unknown.`

Comment: I was wondering, as for the case `1.` at least, wouldn't `-dt` be enough ?