# Nanohttpd exits immediately when run in Docker container

Tags: java, docker, nanohttpd

I wrote a simple microservice in Java using nanohttpd for the HTTP server. I am able to run it from the jar file directly from the Windows 10 command prompt like this:

```
D:\Docker\JoeMicroserviceTest\src>java -jar JoeMicroserviceTest-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

The server starts fine and displays:

> Server started, Hit Enter to stop.

I can then make HTTP requests against the server, and everything works great.

I then put it in a Docker image, and when I run it, the container starts, the nanohttpd server starts, then immediately stops.  This is what I see:

> Server started, Hit Enter to stop.
>
> Server stopped.

There is pretty much no delay between the starting and stopping. And then of course my container exits because the server process stopped.

Here is my dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:8
COPY ./src/ /usr/src/JoeMicroserviceTest
WORKDIR /usr/src/JoeMicroserviceTest
CMD ["java","-jar","JoeMicroserviceTest-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
EXPOSE 8080
```

I build it like this:

```
docker build -t joe-microservice-test .
```

I run it like this:

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 joe-microservice-test
```

Why could this be happening?

Comment: add `-d` to run it in background (`Detached`)

Comment: @BMW, I just tried that. It outputs a long string of characters then goes back to the command prompt. If I run "docker ps" it does not list any containers, and I can't make any HTTP requests against the server, so it does not seem to be running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I got this working by adding "-dit" to the run command. Here is the working run command:

```
docker run -dit -p 8080:8080 joe-microservice-test
```

Here's [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41916435/practically-what-is-the-difference-between-docker-run-dit-vs-docker-run-d) that helps explain why it's needed.